# Sort array of buttons programmatically in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, button

I have a big number of buttons added programatically by user.
Buttons are created by x and y number (user inputs them).
For each x there is an y button.
So, if my x number is 2, and y number is 3 then I will have buttons named and inserted on form like:

[image: image1]

Now, how can I, using two FOR statements, position buttons on the form like:

[image]

This is my code so far:

```
int left = 50;
int top = 50;
int all_zd=x*y;
Button[] btn_arr = new Button[all_zd];
for (int i = 1; i <=y; i++ ) 
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= x; j++)
    {
        //Button btn = new Button();
        btn_arr[j] = new Button();
        {
            btn_arr[j].Name = j.ToString() + "t" + i.ToString();
            btn_arr[j].Text = j.ToString() + "ff" + i.ToString();
            btn_arr[j].Height = 20;
            btn_arr[j].Width = 50;
            btn_arr[j].Location = new Point(left,top);
            top += btn_arr[j].Height + 2; 
            this.Controls.Add(btn_arr[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe the if statement?

```
if ((i == 1 && j % x == 1) top+= btn_arr[j].Height + 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the both ways to you, create vertical buttons and horizontal buttons.

```
    private void CreateVerticalButtons()
    {
        const int LEFT = 200;
        var top = 50;
        var x = int.Parse(X.Text);
        var y = int.Parse(Y.Text);

        for (var i = 1; i <= y; i++)
        {
            for (var j = 1; j <= x; j++)
            {
                var btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = string.Format("{0}ff{1}", j, i);
                btn.Height = 20; btn.Width = 50;
                btn.Top = top;
                btn.Left = LEFT;
                top += 22;
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }
        }
    }

    private void CreateHorizontalButtons()
    {
        const int TOP = 100;
        var left = 200;

        var x = int.Parse(X.Text);
        var y = int.Parse(Y.Text);

        for (var i = 1; i <= y; i++)
        {
            var top = TOP;
            for (var j = 1; j <= x; j++)
            {
                var btn = new Button();
                btn.Text = string.Format("{0}ff{1}", j, i);
                btn.Height = 20; btn.Width = 50;
                btn.Top = top;
                btn.Left = left;
                top -= 22;
                this.Controls.Add(btn);
            }

            left += 52;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
  var left = 0;
  var top = 0;
  var btnWith = 20;
  var btnHeigh = 50;


  int x = 2, y = 3;
  for (var i = 0; i < x; i++)
  {
    for (var j = 0; j < y; j++)
    {
      var btn = new Button();
      btn.Name = j + "t" + i;
      btn.Text = j + "ff" + i;
      btn.Height = btnHeigh ;
      btn.Width = btnWith;
      btn.Location = new Point(left, top);

      left += btnWith;
      Controls.Add(btn);
    }
    top += btnHeigh;
  }
```